# rosparam param="source_list"

Tags: roslaunch, rosparam

I don't know what `<rosparam param="source_list">` means and barely found a clear description of it, especially on the official website. Here is the snippet I found online

```
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
        <rosparam param="source_list">["hand_model/joint_states"]</rosparam>
   </node>
```

Is `source_list` a description of the data transmitted via topic `hand_model/joint_states`?

A detailed explanation would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xml tag has nothing to do with ros publish/subscribe. ros1 provides a simple key/value property database called the "parameter server".

For this tag, `param` specifies the property name you want to create (or overwrite) on the parameter server. If the property name does not start with a `/`, the string is prepended with the current node namespace.

For the example you show, the full parameter property name is: `/joint_state_publisher/source_list`.

This property is assigned the value: `["hand_model/joint_states"]`

The value in a rosparam tag is defined to be yaml, so the square brackets cause this value to be parsed as a yaml list **before** it is stored to the parameter server.

If you just want to store a basic literal string, int or float value, most people use the `<param .../>` tag instead (which does not perform this yaml parsing.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, there can be more than one rostopic inside the square bracket, right?

Comment: It depends. For the `rosparam` tag, you can store any legal yaml string into the property. But then it is up to the ros node that later reads the property to know how to interpret it. If the ros node expects a list, you can use a list.